# What's the class/id of the Firefox right-click menu?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'd like to write a userstyle to modify the right-click menu in Firefox, but need its XUL class and ID. What is it?

(I'd usually use DOM Inspector to find it out, but one can't inspect a right-click menu because focus is lost when switching to the DOM Inspector window.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right click context menu that appears when you right click on a webpage has the id = `contentAreaContextMenu`. You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions#Modifying_the_context_menu) some information on modifying it.

Comment: for future searchers, the css selector to the items is `#contentAreaContextMenu menuitem`, and for the nested menus `#contentAreaContextMenu menu`.